# UFT (QTP 11.5) Request API sent without security in the Header

Tags: api, security, qtp

I need to run secure ws.
When I run it from SOAP UI I use basic security with username.
in the UFT I defined Username token on port.
but when I run the API I get an error: "An invalid security token was provided".
In the request API I dont see the security element

What am I missing

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the security on the port, please check that the "Use port security settings" is checked in the security tab in the properties pane of the step (it should be by default).
The security headers are not printed to the user log pane, but you can find them in the "vtd_internal.log" file, located at: /Log directory.
Is the "An invalid security token was provided" message from UFT or from the server?
do you get the same message if you don't use and security settings on the step?

Comment: thanks Yossi - in the log I saw that the security element is indeed sent. after playing with nonce and timestamp checkboxes finally got successful response from the server.